# Unmount / destroy Component in jsdom test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsdom

Is there a way to unmount and garbage collect a React Component that was mounted using `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` inside a jsdom test?

I'm trying to test something that happens on `componentWillUnmount` and `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` doesn't return any DOM node to call `React. unmountComponentAtNode` on.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, but you can simply use `ReactDOM.render` manually:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(<Component />, container);
// ...
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
```

This is exactly [what ReactTestUtils does anyway](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/87bcbff/src/test/ReactTestUtils.js#L50-L58), so there's no reason not to do it this way if you need a reference to the container.

Comment: I wrote a little bit about this here with some examples:  http://maketea.co.uk/2014/05/22/building-robust-web-apps-with-react-part-3.html#react-test-utilities

Comment: This is not valid anymore as renderIntoDocument does not touch DOM whatsoever.

Answer (score 22):

Calling `componentWillUnmount` directly won't work for any children that need to clean up things on unmount. And you also don't really need to replicate the `renderIntoDocument` method, either since you can just use `parentNode`:

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(React.findDOMNode(component).parentNode);
```

Update: as of React 15 you need to use `ReactDOM` to achieve the same:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// ...
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component).parentNode);
```

Comment: As of React 15 you need to use ReactDOM to do this:
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component).parentNode);

Answer (score 8):

Just to update @SophieAlpert answer. React.renderComponent will be deprecated soon so you should use ReactDOM methods instead:

```
var container = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(<Component />, container);
// ...
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
```

Answer (score 0):

After your test you can call componentWillUnmount() on the component manually.

```
beforeEach ->
  @myComponent = React.addons.TestUtils.renderIntoDocument <MyComponent/>

afterEach ->
  @myComponent.componentWillUnmount()
```

Comment: This is doable if you update props after rendering, but if you need to pass different combinations of props that becomes cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this question, figure I would provide a way to directly tackle it using the described renderIntoDocument API. This solution works in the context of PhantomJS.

To mount onto the document node:

```
theComponent = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent/>);
```

To unmount from the document node:

```
React.unmountComponentAtNode(document);
```