# Testing React componentWillUnmount using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am using React's `TestUtil.renderIntoDocument` to test a React component class, [like this](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#content) (only I am using TypeScript instead of Babel):

```
describe("MyComponent", () => {
  it("will test something after being mounted", () => {
    var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<MyComponent />);
    // some test...
  })
})
```

This works, but I want to write a test that verifies that `componentWillUnmount` behaves as expected. However, it seems that the test runner never unmounts the component, which is not surprising. So my question is: how do I unmount the component from within a test? The `TestUtil` doesn't have anything that looks like what I want, something along the lines of `removeFromDocument` I would imagine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unmount / destroy Component in jsdom test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973942/unmount-destroy-component-in-jsdom-test)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's right but `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` returns a ReactComponent with access to the lifecycle methods of the component.

So you can call manually `component.componentWillUnmount()`.

Comment: In my case I had to call `component.instance().componentWillUnmount()`. Calling it directly on the component didn't work.

Answer (score 21):

Using `enzyme 3` library's `shallow()` and `unmount()`, you can test if lifecycle methods have been called like this:

```
it(`lifecycle method should have been called`, () => {
  const componentDidMount = jest.fn()
  const componentWillUnmount = jest.fn()

  // 1. First extends your class to mock lifecycle methods
  class Foo extends MyComponent {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.componentDidMount = componentDidMount
      this.componentWillUnmount = componentWillUnmount
    }

    render() {
      return (<MyComponent />)
    }
  }

  // 2. shallow-render and test componentDidMount
  const wrapper = shallow(<Foo />)

  expect(componentDidMount.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
  expect(componentWillUnmount.mock.calls.length).toBe(0)

  // 3. unmount and test componentWillUnmount
  wrapper.unmount()

  expect(componentDidMount.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
  expect(componentWillUnmount.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
})
```

Comment: My original (very old) question was about Facebook's TestUtils, but indeed Enzyme is a way better solution and I've long since switched to use it instead.

Comment: Thanks so much! `wrapper.unmount()` is what I was looking for. Personally, I don't think it's worth testing that the React lifecycle methods work correctly, but instead, the test should check that the code *within* the lifecycle methods is behaving correctly.

Comment: @Jay I kind of agree. I am interested in moving to ‘react-testing-library’ that encourages not testing implementation details.

Answer (score 14):

> ```
> Step1: Use "jest.spyOn" on "componentWillUnmount" method.
> Step2: Trigger unmount on the mounted component.
> Finally: check if componentWillUnmount is called when component is unmounted
> ```

Code

```
it('componentWillUnmount should be called on unmount', () => {
    const component = createComponent();
    const componentWillUnmount = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), 'componentWillUnmount');
    component.unmount();
    expect(componentWillUnmount).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
...

let container;
beforeEach(() => {
   container = document.createElement("div");
   mount(<YourReactComponent />, {attachTo: container});
});

afterEach(() => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container);
});
```

Comment: Yes I've since switched to enzyme which solved this and a lot of other limitations with FB's test utils. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I've tried everything but only this solution worked. I don't know what exactly happens with Enzyme in order to need this kind of workaround. Thanks a lot. +1

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function call in componentWillUnmount:

```
componentWillUnmount(){
    this.foo();
}
```

In the test you can do:

```
const wrapper = mount(<YourComponent />);
const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.instance(), 'foo');
wrapper.unmount();
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```